# How to read all NSDictionary objects for a key to an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary "playerDict" that reads data from a plist where there is names (myKey) with nine associated objects to each key.

I am trying to read all objects for a specific key (myKeys) into an NSMutableArray (theObjects). I have read the class reference and search internet but cannot figure our this, probably very simple, problem.

Among all other test i have done I have tried the following but that returns the key into theObjects and not the objects.

> theObjects = [playerDict objectForKey:myKeys];

Anyone that could give a hint?

Here is the code that created the dict, i stripped it:

```
NSArray *objs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:playerObject.diffHard],[NSNumber numberWithBool:playerObject.diffMedium],
             [NSNumber numberWithBool:playerObject.diffEasy],[NSNumber numberWithBool:playerObject.currentGame],
             [NSNumber numberWithInt:playerObject.currentGameQuestion],[NSNumber numberWithInt:playerObject.currentGameRightAnswer],
             [NSNumber numberWithInt:playerObject.currentGameType],[NSNumber numberWithInt:playerObject.nrOfType0Games],
             [NSNumber numberWithInt:playerObject.type0Result], nil];
NSDictionary *newPlayerDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:objs, keyString, nil];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try valueForKey:

Comment: I do not know what i did wrong before with valueForKey but now it finally works. A BIG thank you to all of you. Maybe it is like i do not see the forrest because of the trees :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can only store one item per key in an `NSDictionary`. If you need story multiple items for the same key, you need to first add each of the items to an `NSArray` (or `NSSet`) that you instead then set as an object in your dictionary.

If might be useful if you posted the code that creates the dictionary.

**Update:** It looks like you are already doing this. So:

```
NSArray *myObjs=[playerDict objectForKey:keyString];
```

will get you your array. And this:

```
BOOL diffHard=[[myObjs objectAtIndex:0] boolValue];
BOOL diffMedium=[[myObjs objectAtIndex:1] boolValue];
```

Will get you the value you stored in the first and second objects of the array. Repeat it for the rest.